# How to get C# Facebook sdk to response no matte profile language?

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

How do I get C # FACEBOOK SDK to always respond in the same language no matter what language the profile?

eg. relationship_status gives me "mand" (male in Danish) with a Danish profile, but "male" with an English profile.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a query just include the &locale=en_US query argument, setting the value to whatever locale you want. For example:

```
dynamic result = app.Api("/me?locale=en_US");
```